# How to share only text using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I want to know if I can share only text (without any link, image, video) to a facebook wall/timeline using facebook android SDK?

I try to find it on facebook developers website, but there isn't example with sharing only text. This is the link to documentation

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See section 2.3 of Facebook's Platform Policies. https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Typically sharing of text only (that your app provides) would violate that policy.

It's possible with ShareContent if you have publish permissions and use the Graph API, but in order to not violate policy you'd need to let the user fill in the text string rather than providing it yourself.